# Could someone explain __declspec(naked) please?

Tags: c, linux, windows, assembly, calling-convention

I'm looking into porting a script engine written for Windows to Linux; it's for Winamp's visualization platform AVS. I'm not sure if it's even possible at the moment. From what I can tell the code is taking the addresses of the C functions `nseel_asm_atan` and `nseel_asm_atan_end` and storing them inside a table that it can reference during code execution.

I've looked at MS's documentation, but I'm unsure what `__declspec(naked)` really does. What is prolog and epilog code mentioned in the documentation? Is that related to Windows calling conventions? Is this portable? Know of any Linux-based examples using similar techniques?

```
static double (*__atan)(double) = &atan;
__declspec ( naked ) void nseel_asm_atan(void)
{
  FUNC1_ENTER

  *__nextBlock = __atan(*parm_a);

  FUNC_LEAVE
}
__declspec ( naked ) void nseel_asm_atan_end(void) {}
```

Comment: This is what they mean by prolog and epilog: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tawsa7cb(VS.80).aspx, I'm pretty sure that you can just `#define __declspec(n)` to expand to nothing for Linux. I think GNU C++ implements something _similar_, but I'm not quite sure what it is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 13):

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) function prologue and epilogue :

> In assembly language programming, the function prologue is a few lines
>   of code at the beginning of a function, which prepare the stack and
>   registers for use within the function. Similarly, the function
>   epilogue appears at the end of the function, and restores the stack
>   and registers to the state they were in before the function was
>   called.

To ensure that the compiler does not auto generate an extra code within the your function , always declare the function using the `__declspec(naked)` convention.

let's take a look at this function :

```
void myTrampoline()
{
__asm {
  PUSHFD
  PUSHAD
  CALL jumpHookCallback
  POPAD
  POPFD
  POP EAX
  MOV AL, 1
  POP EDI
  POP ESI
  JMP [restoreJumpHook]
 }
}
```

now the compiler will generate code that manipulate the stack frame of the function called as prologue  and epilogue  of function and the result will look like this

```
;Prologue
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, N

PUSHFD
PUSHAD
CALL jumpHookCallback
POPAD
POPFD
POP EAX
MOV AL, 1
POP EDI
POP ESI
JMP [restoreJumpHook]

;Epilogue
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

but if we use  `__declspec(naked)` there will be no   `Prologue` no  `Epilogue`

```
void __declspec(naked) myTrampoline()
{
__asm {
  PUSHFD
  PUSHAD
  CALL jumpHookCallback
  POPAD
  POPFD
  POP EAX
  MOV AL, 1
  POP EDI
  POP ESI
  JMP [restoreJumpHook]
 }
}
```

and the result will look like this :

```
    PUSHFD
    PUSHAD
    CALL jumpHookCallback
    POPAD
    POPFD
    POP EAX
    MOV AL, 1
    POP EDI
    POP ESI
    JMP [restoreJumpHook]
```

Answer (score 12):

Basically the function prologue sets up a stack frame for local variables and the epilogue takes care of cleaning it up. This is usually done automatically by the compiler. If you use `__declspec(naked)`, setting up this stack frame will be up to you so it gives you more flexibility.

There are many references: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tawsa7cb%28VS.80%29.aspx) , [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue), [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886836/writing-naked-functions-with-custom-prolog-and-epilog-code-in-visual-studio)  and more.

The GNU gcc compiler also supports naked, but apparently not for x86: [search for "naked" in the page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)  (I haven't tried to see if it works on x86)

Comment: Update, `__attribute__((naked))` is supported on x86 by gcc and clang these days, but wasn't in 2010.  Also worth mentioning that putting anything other than inline asm inside a naked function is not supported on most compilers.  The code in the question only uses global variables, so will normally happen to work, but I don't see any benefit to a naked function for it over simply enabling optimization.